# Manipulating posts

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I'm beginning to help a new nonprofit create a website. I'd thought that I might use WordPress.com, just to speed things up and to have someone else keep track of maintenance and security. As I look into what the group wants, however, I'm realizing that a lot of doesn't seem to be native to WordPress.

They want to have users sort through posts (no problem with Categories and Tags), but then users should be able to submit their own posts, which after approval would then be sortable and selectable as well. I know that there are user types that would allow this piece, but they're kind of clunky. And of course there are also plugins, if I decide to use downloadable WordPress and worry about updating the thing.

Ideally, users would also select their favorite posts and collect them into some sort of document. I don't know of a way to do this in WordPress.

I can code all of this myself and just have a WordPress site point to it (I think!), but then the maintenance and security advantages fade.

It seems that I might be best off just starting from the ground up (probably using RoR), but I'm wondering if anyone either knows of a good way to manipulate WordPress into doing what I need, or perhaps knows of a CMS that might help me get a quick start and then accommodate some of the extra functionality I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this can be done 100% using WordPress and off-the-shelf plugins (some paid).  The only question mark is the "collect them into some sort of document" (not sure what that means, actually).  Writing a CMS is not easy, and while you could potentially do it from scratch, why not at least start with a proven framework (such as WP) that gets you 98% of the way there, and code the last 2% yourself?

Comment: Thank you! By "collect them into some sort of document" I mean create a PDF or a webpage incorporating just the selected posts, so that the user may use it for a presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you are going to do can easily be done with WordPress (standalone). You do not need any Ruby on Rails or any additional framework or CMS. WordPress.com may have limitations in some points.

You can create individual user roles and capabilities (https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

You can use the user_meta table to save individual user preferences such as post IDs (get_user_meta() / add_user_meta() / update_user_meta()).

You can create a custom output by creating a custom Plugin or by creating a custom Theme in order to export your users' favorite posts.

All you need is some basic programming knowledge in PHP and also some specific knowledge about WordPress. Start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: Thanks so much! I've used WordPress before, but clearly need to explore it more.